# count characters in a masked textbox for check

Tags: vb.net

I am using a masked TextBox, and I would like to check the input (total characters must be 14),
is there a property for the masked TextBox to handle this or should I use a function?
Can someone help me?

Comment: Not a Clear Question! Please try to make it clear

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do it with this:

```
' Remove spaces
Dim textNoSpaces As String = TextBox1.Text.Replace(" ", "")

If textNoSpaces.Length <> 14 Then
    ' Do something here
Else
    ' Do something else, if desired
End If
```

The masking is a display thing, it has nothing to do with the actual string entered by the user.

Comment: the problem is that "space" is also counted !!So the count will be always 14! How can I help this ? If I start the input at position number 5 to 14, the space before number 5 is also counted!!

Comment: @ramajoud1 - You're welcome - glad it worked.  When you get a moment, kindly accept my answer.  Thanks :)